# How to display error messages in separate line

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

In struts 1 i am trying to handle errors using  tag but i can see all my error message and coming in the same line.I want to display the error messages in different lines.

I am using this method in my LoginForm extends ActionForm.

```
@Override
    public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {

        System.out.println("Validate Method is called!");

        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

        if(getName()==null||getName().equals(""))
        {
            errors.add("useError", new ActionMessage("error.common.name.required"));
        }

        if(getPass()==null||getPass().equals(""))
        {
            errors.add("passError", new ActionMessage("error.common.pass.required"));
        }

        return errors;
    }
```

I get output like this .

```
Name is requiredPassword is required
```

This is my Error.property file

```
#Error Messages
error.common.name.required = Name is required
error.common.pass.required = Password is required
error.common.message.invalidCredentials = Invalid Id or Password
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to add a newline character after you have added each corresponding error.

Comment: You don't show how you're displaying them, so I don't know how we're supposed to help. You can either iterate and display each however you want, or use the `errors.header` etc. properties, e.g., http://www.jajakarta.org/struts/struts1.2/documentation/ja/target/userGuide/struts-html.html#errors.

Comment: @JoanPlepi Its not working like that.

Comment: @DaveNewton Its a table cell above my input text box. I have resolved it by creating some common message insted of 2 different error messages

Comment: That's fine, but it seems like it might be a requirement at some point... Although this was from three years ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place `<br>` or `\n` to each message.

```
error.common.name.required = Name is required<br>
```

Comment: sounds tricky but adding <br> tag in property file is not a good idea i guess because we are trying to add html code in property file